# Issue with full screen mode in qt5

Tags: qt

I have an application in qml. I am using quickview and setting it as full screen. But when I try to open a .ui file(QWidget) from full screen mode it is going behind the mainwindow. this doesn't happen when I am not in full screen mode. I have tried setting flag (Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint) but it doesn't work. I am using QT5 . Thanks for the help

```
 QUiLoader loader;
 QFile file("abc.ui");
 file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
 QWidget * _parent = loader.load(&file);
 file.close();
 _parent->setParent(mainlayout);
 _parent->setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool);
 _parent->setWindowFlags(_parent->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

In this the mainlayout is quickview

Comment: Did you try `mainwindow.hide()`?

Comment: the .ui file is kind of a dialog it will not cover the whole screen .

Comment: You will need to show this as a minimal test case. You don't need any QML, simply create an empty QLabel, show it full screen, create a simple dialog programmatically (even an empty dialog), and reproduce it. It needs to be one file, a couple dozen lines at most.

Answer (score 0):

The widget parenting behavior in Qt differs between `QDialog` and `QWidget`. A `QDialog` is always a top-level widget (a window). I guess that your the object that your `.ui` file creates is not a `QDialog`. Please ensure that it is:

```
QWidget * _parent = loader.load(&file);
Q_ASSERT(qobject_cast<QDialog*>(_parent));
```

If this assert fails, then you need to change your `.ui` file's base class to be a dialog.

You should probably also activate and raise your dialog:

```
_parent->activateWindow();
_parent->raise();
```

Comment: i tried it. Assertion is not failing but activating and raising dialog is not working.